# Is it possible to add a suffix to a jQuery mask?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mask

I'm using Igor Escobar's jQuery mask plugin (https://github.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin) and I'm trying to add a suffix to a mask to show a `%` sign at the end of the input value.

The application I'm building is for Brazilian users, then I have to use this number format: `000.000,00`. Where `,` (comma) is the decimal separator and `.` (dot) is the thousand separator.

I wrote the following code to apply the mask, not yet appending the `%` sign at the end of it.

```
$('.mask-decimal').each(function () {
    var $self = $(this);
    var precision = parseInt($self.data('precision'), 10) || 2;
    var mask = '#.##0,' + (new Array(precision + 1).join('0'));
    $self.mask(mask, {
        reverse : true,
        maxlength : false
    });
    $self.on('keyup', function () {
        var val = this.value;
        if (val) {
            if (val.length <= precision) {
                while (val.length < precision) {
                    val = '0' + val;
                }
                val = '0,' + val;
            } else {
                var parts = val.split(',');
                parts[0] = parts[0].replace(/^0+/, '');
                if (parts[0].length === 0) {
                    parts[0] = '0';
                }
                val = parts.join(',');
            }
            this.value = val;
        }
    });
});
```

This mask works perfectly.

What I tried to do was add the percent symbol at the end of the mask, then remove it just in the beginning of my `keyup` handler, and finally append it again before return the value. I basically changed these lines:

```
var mask = '#.##0,' + (new Array(precision + 1).join('0')) + '%';

var val = this.value.replace('%', '');

this.value = val + '%';
```

After change that, I can input a value in the field, but I can't clear/change it using backspace. If I'm fast enough I can select the entire content and delete it, but it's an awful solution for regular users. It happens this way because the cursor stays always at the end of the input and the keyup event is triggered very quickly.

With that in mind, there is a way to move the cursor to a specific position inside the input? Does somebody can see another way to change my function so the user can use the backspace to clear the input contents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is for an input field and the `%` sign is just for decoration, you could position a span containing the symbol above the input. Because it's purely a display item, right? Or you could have the sign after the input.

There's absolutely no need to have it in the input if the user's not supposed to be able to edit it. It's counterintuitive both for the user and for your logic.

Here I put the sign inside a label just so that clicking it will activate the input field.

```css
label, input {
  font-size:18px;
  font-family:sans-serif;
}

label {
  margin-left:-24px;
}

input {
  text-align:right;
  padding-right:24px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="number" value="123">
<label for="number">%</label>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jan. Actually, I'm using Bootstrap, so I can use an input add on for that. I was only wondering if it's possible to append the `%` sign to the input value as the project owner requested. If no other answer show up, I'll do as you advised.

Comment: Of course it's possible, you've already done it. But you're having x problems with it because it's a Bad Idea. Your product owner should be telling you what they want to achieve, not how you're supposed to do it. They lack the technical knowledge to make those kind of decisions.

Comment: @GustavoStraube See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem If this is your setup for project management (project manager tells you what to do, not what they want), I would request to revise that process if I were you. I can not stress this enough, project owners are (usually) not technically qualified to make requests in that manner and it will definitely ensure a lower quality product. For yours AND your client's sake, revise your decision making process.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. BTW I followed your answer and I added a visual indication of the kind of value (percentage) rather than change the mask.